# What do the terms "cuts" and "jumpers" mean?

Tags: power-engineering

specifically, with respect to the **electrical grid**.

Here's an excerpt from something that I'm reading that I don't understand:

> Switching operations, including applying cuts and jumpers, can be operated in ganged (all phases in one operation) or un-ganged (one or more selected phases) mode.

Comment: Some context ... ?

Comment: Do you have a bit more context? A link to the webpage, or title of the book/article?

Comment: [PowerOn™ Fusion Advanced Distribution Management System. Page 4 left column, last paragraph on "Smart switching"](http://www.gedigitalenergy.com/products/brochures/uos/PowerOn_fusion.pdf) and https://duckduckgo.com/ to the rescue.

Comment: I'm used to cuts and jumpers on a PCB board; this is something on an entirely different scale.

Comment: @tcrosley I have a feeling the terms were borrowed from the smaller electronics world, and therefore mean very similar things.

Comment: @NikoBellic The various components on a PCB are connected by very thin "traces".  Sometimes, usually when making the first (or second etc.) versions of a PCB, an engineer will discover they have made a mistake, and a trace needs to go to a different pin or pad than what was originally laid out.  So the trace between points A and B is cut, usually with an X-Acto knife, and then a jumper is soldered between say points A and C using a thin wire, usually 30 gauge or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context appears to be switching of a power grid while troubleshooting and repairing things.

In that context, a 'cut' might be where you physically cut a conductor (as a prerequisite to repairing it with a new bit of conductor.)

A 'jumper' might be where you temporarily connect two conductors which aren't usually connected, for the purposes of working around a fault.

The software in question seems to be for monitoring the status of a power system in real time, so that the grid operator can tell which bits of the grid are alive (not safe to work on), and which bits are dead (safe to work on). Tracking 'cuts' and 'jumpers' would be important as they are very temporary by nature, and might not be well tracked by software which has a fixed model of switching locations.

Answer (score 0):

A cut is when you cut an existing conductor. A jumper is when you connect two circuit nodes with a conductor. I imagine it means the same thing for power lines. So if you needed to add an isolation transformer, you would first cut the line to create an open circuit, then jump the transmission line to the transformer. If a line got damaged by a storm, you might have to cut out a piece of bad wire, and jump in a piece of new wire to repair the system.